# Why does my car keep having high RPMs and not speeding up over 10-15 MPH?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, rpm, aveo

it’s done this twice in exactly a week and every time I take it to the mechanic the check engine light turns off and they don’t do anything. It’s a 2009 Chevy Aveo

Comment: Manual or automatic? How high are the RPM you're reaching? The CEL will reset after some time if the error condition does not repeat, so have it scanned sooner rather than later next time.

Comment: check engine light should store a code for roughly 50 on/off cycles for a vehicle

Comment: @schizoid04, it differs by manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your IAC valve or Idle Air Control valve. It regulates idle speed. Sometimes they are dirty and can just be cleaned. A new part cost around $20-40.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the throttle body is dirty. This happened to me, in a 2009 Chevy Aveo, but at higher speeds, over 50 MPH, so not a big chance for the lower speeds, but adding this answer in case someone else has the issue at higher RPMs.